# Can't retrieve variable values from dynamically generated Tkinter checkboxes

Tags: python, tkinter, checkbox, dynamic

Per the title, the dynamically generated variables refuse to surrender their values, and the code incorrectly outputs

`Selected: foo bar baz qux`

regardless of whether the respective checkboxes are selected. I've reviewed dozens of related 'tkinter dynamically created checkbox' search results on Google, and I can't find anything to make this work.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('200x400')


def inspect_checkboxes():
    output = 'Selected: '
    for i in range(len(checkbox_names)):
        if checkbox_vars[i] == 1:
            output = output + checkbox_names[i] + ' '
    label = Label(root, text=output)
    label.pack()


checkbox_names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'qux']
checkbox_vars = []
for i in range(len(checkbox_names)):
    checkbox_vars.append(IntVar())
    checkbox = Checkbutton(root, 
        text=checkbox_names[i], 
        variable=checkbox_vars[i], 
        onvalue=1, 
        offvalue=0)
    checkbox.pack()

button = Button(root, text='Inspect Checkboxes', command=inspect_checkboxes)
button.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: hint: `checkbox_vars[i]` is an `IntVar`, not an integer. It will never be equal to any integer.

Comment: @BryanOakley I added `.get()` and voila! Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.